# Python filter string

Tags: python-3.x, binance-api-client

With the following command i can print the balance of my assets from my binance ac.

Command:

```
USDT_BAL = client.futures_account_balance(asset='USDT')
```

Return:

```
[{'accountAlias': 'sRuXXqTioCfWFz', 'asset': 'BNB', 'balance': '0.00000142', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000142', 'updateTime': 1621516315044}, {'accountAlias': 'sRuXXqTioCfWFz', 'asset': 'USDT', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}, {'accountAlias': 'sRuXXqTioCfWFz', 'asset': 'BUSD', 'balance': '0.00000000', 'withdrawAvailable': '0.00000000', 'updateTime': 0}]
```

It returns the balances of other assets, but i only need the balance of the USDT asset. How could I filter the USDT_BAL variable for it?

Comment: `next((i['balance'] for i in USDT_BAL if i['asset'] == 'USDT'), None)` should work. It would return the balance for the `'USDT'` asset if it exists, otherwise `None`.

Comment: Could you explain how it works?

Comment: I added it as an answer and went into a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

You have a `list` of `dict`. `list` access is done by iteration (`for` loops) or by indexes. `my_list[0]`, etc..

`dict` access can, also done by iteration, but a big benefit is keyed access. `my_dict['some_key']`, etc..

Python has simplified ways to do common `list` and `dict` building commonly called "comprehensions".

So a `list` comprehension for something like:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(10):
    my_list.append(i)
```

Could be written as

```
my_list = [i for i in range(10)]
```

What I gave you isn't necessarily a `list` comprehension but follows the same idea. It's called a "generator expression". The difference is it generates some output when you iterate over it but it's output as a whole isn't in the form of some built-in collection (`list` or `dict`).

The reason it makes sense in this context is:

1. I need to iterate over the `list` to find `dict` with the correct `'asset'` key.
2. I expect there is only one occurrence of this so I care only about the first occurrence.

So to break it down you have a generator expression:

```
(i['balance'] for i in USDT_BAL if i['asset'] == 'USDT')
```

Which is roughly equivalent to.

```
def my_gen():
    for i in USDT_BAL:
        if i['asset'] == 'USDT':
            yield i['balance']
```

Or if you're not familiar with generators and would like it as a `list`:

```
my_list = []
for i in USDT_BAL:
    if i['asset'] == 'USDT':
        my_list.append(i['balance'])
```

So now you can see we have a problem.
If we have it as a `list` comprehension it's in the form of a `list` with one element.

```
print(my_list) # ['0.00000000']
```

We could access it with `my_list[0]` but that looks ugly IMO but to each it's own.

So that's where the `next` function comes in.
According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) `next` calls the `__next__` method on an iterator (which a generator is) and basically advances the generator.
So if our generator were to produce `1` then `2` then `3`, calling `next(my_gen)` would produce `1` then calling it again would produce `2` and so on.

Since I expect this generator expression to only produce 1 item, I only call it once. Giving it a default of `None` means, if it's empty, rather than raising an error it will produce `None`.

So:

```
next((i['balance'] for i in USDT_BAL if i['asset'] == 'USDT'), None)
```

creates a generator that iterates over your `list`, only produces the `'balance'` key of `dict`s who's `'asset'` key equals `'USDT'` and calls `next` on that generator with a default of `None`.